# Access element inside colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colorbox

```
$.colorbox({ href: previewLink, iframe: true, width: "90%", height: "90%" });
```

I am using the above code to call colorbox. Once the colorbox is displayed I would like access and element inside the colorbox and then change the css.

However I am unable to access elements inside the colorbox.

I tried the following:

```
$(function () {

    'use strict';

    setInterval(
        function () {

            console.log("logging...");

            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("className");
            if (elements.length > 0) {
                console.log("Found element");
            }

        }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: assuming `getElementsByClassName` is supported in your browser (ie9+) can you reproduct in a fiddle? without seeing the html being rendered it's hard to know if any element has a class of 'className'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use timeout for this purpose, always look for *events*. The colorbox haves `onOpen` event([CTRL+F "Callbacks"](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)), which I think fits your needs:

```
$.colorbox({ 
    href: previewLink, 
    iframe: true, 
    width: "90%", 
    height: "90%",
    onOpen: function()
    {
        debugger;
        $("#colorbox").find(); // Find desired element
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ozwu91ov/).

Furthermore, why are you using `getElementsByClassName` if you already have jQuery on your page? Why not `.find()` ?